# Proving $n < 2m$

Tags: inequality

If $m, n$ are integers between $1$ and $1981$ and satisfy $(n^2-mn-m^2)^2=1, n>m, $  how could I prove  $n < 2m?$

I tried $$n = \frac m n \times m + \frac 1 n +m < 1 \times m +m + \frac 1 n=2m+ \frac 1 n$$

So I have extra $\frac 1 n$, but I need the inequality without it. This is a part of a problem from 22nd IMO.

Comment: Isn't $(n, m) = (2, 1)$ a counterexample to your statement?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375504/statistical-proof-of-tur%c3%a1n-s-graph-theorem-weight-of-vertex-uniformly-distribut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you get $$n<2m+{1\over n}\implies n<2m+1\implies n\leq 2m$$

Now let's see what happen if $n=2m$...

Comment: We get $(m,n)=(1,2)$, so?

Comment: Then you can not prove your statement unless you add a constraint $m>1$.

Comment: Thanks mate, I do understand that but the book I am reading does not have such constraint,  I wonder how they manage to prove that!!

Comment: I wonder too. If you like an answer, please, do upvote.