# Does anyone know what this theorem is?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

During a computational complexities class, the professor stated the following theorem, without naming it.

Let $G$ be a graph, with adjacency matrix $A$, and clique-number $k$. i.e. the largest clique in $G$ has size $k$, then

$$ 1-\frac{1}{k} = \max\left\{\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}A_{i,j}p_ip_j \ \Big|\ \forall i\ p_i\geq 0,\sum_i p_i =1\right\}$$

Does anyone know what theorem this is?

Comment: What does $C_L(A_G)$ mean?

Comment: it is the maximum size of the cliques in the graph with adjacency matrix AG

Comment: I think the simplest way to answer this question is to ask your professor.

Comment: I edited the question and decided to leave it open, as I found the theorem interesting, and never saw it stated this way. And now that I've seen Misha's answer, this is a huge gap in my knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Turán's theorem, which says that an $n$-vertex graph with clique number $k$ has at most $(1 - \frac1k)\frac{n^2}{2}$ edges.

Specifically, Turán's theorem follows from setting $p = (\frac1n, \frac1n, \dots, \frac1n)$ in the result you're quoting. In that case, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} p_i p_j$ contributes $\frac{2}{n^2}$ for every edge, so it is $\frac{2m}{n^2}$ for an $m$-edge graph. If this sum can be at most $1 - \frac1k$, then we conclude $m \le (1 - \frac1k) \frac{n^2}{2}$.

The general result that $1 - \frac1k$ is the maximum over **all** nonnegative vectors $p$ with sum $1$ doesn't have a name. We usually prove it in the course of proving Turán's theorem;
see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375504) on MSE for some discussion. This can be done in an ad-hoc way or using Lagrange multipliers.